# How to avoid multiple error message?

Tags: angular5, angular-forms

In my `FormControl` i see both error enabled at a time. how to prevent this? I require to show only one on the time by condition:

```
<div *ngIf="senderPostalcode.errors && (senderPostalcode.dirty || senderPostalcode.touched )" class="error">{{senderPostalcodeError}}</div> //let show only when error and  dirty
<div *ngIf="senderPostalcode?.errors?.maxlength || senderPostalcode?.errors?.minlength"  class="error">{{senderPostalcodeLEN_BET}}</div> // when this show rest can disapear
```

What is the condition need i require to add here?

Comment: This is probably what you want (as opposed to writing redundant and convoluted logical expressions): https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `div` will be shown on every error when your control is touched and dirty: `"senderPostalcode.errors && (senderPostalcode.dirty || senderPostalcode.touched )"`

To hide this `div` on `min` and `max` error add: `"senderPostalcode.errors && (senderPostalcode.dirty || senderPostalcode.touched ) && !senderPostalcode.errors.maxlength && !senderPostalcode.errors.minlength"` 
When you receive `min` or `max` error this `div` will not be shown.

Comment: Do you have any idea to add the regex to fail the text field when has only white spaces?

Comment: Do you mean to validate input on white spaces?

Comment: @3gwebtrain Do you mean to make validation not to allow only white spaces?

Comment: @3gwebtrain If that is what you were asking then use regex pattern: `^\s*$` This pattern will match `all white spaces` in input field.